# JSF works in Firefox but blank page in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf-2

I have a login.xhtml file that displays fine in Firefox however when I open the same page in Internet Explorer I get a blank page with just the background color set by the CSS file. I have tried IE8 and IE10. I have not had trouble displaying JSF code in IE in any of my other JSF projects expect this one. Again, the program functions perfectly in Firefox. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Here is my login.xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="last">   
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/css/global.css" />
        <title>Annual Review</title>
    </f:facet>      
</h:head>

<h:body>
<p:layout fullpage="true" >

<p:layoutUnit position="north" size="80" minSize="80" maxSize="80">                 
    <p:panelGrid styleClass="menuBarGrid" columns="2">
        <p:graphicImage url="/css/NeedhamLogo2.bmp" />              
        <h:outputText value="Annual Compliance Questionnaire" />                    
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
</h:body>

</html>
```

And my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AnnualReview</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/annual_review</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

I am using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 4.0 and Glassfish 4.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the `<servlet-mapping><url-pattern>` in my web.xml file from `*.xhtml` to `/faces/*` and the page now displays in IE.

Answer (score -1):

Why do not you use "outputStylesheet" instead of "link"! I do believe that it is not a good idea at all to abandon JSF components. 
If you have a css folder in your resource folder, you should try this one:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="global.css" library="css" />
```

You would better change your p:graphicImage too. Use these two properties instead of pure url. I mean "name" and "library".

Answer (score -2):

It seems this is happening because .ui-layout-unit has visibility = hidden.

Override the .ui-layout-unit in your css as:

```
.ui-layout-unit{
    overflow-x:visible !important; 
    overflow-y:visible !important;
```

}